# How do I serve the same static content from any subdomain of my main domain?

Tags: html, nginx, server, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I have static content that I serve through my domain ***example.com***

But, I want to serve the same static content to users who come to these subdomains too.

***sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com**
...*

I understand that I can setup a wildcard and redirect the incoming request to the main site.
But I don't want to redirect, but rather the content be served from that subdomain itself. Users should still be able to see sub1.example.com in the address bar, as if the site was configured already in that subdomain.

But these subdomains(sub1, sub2 etc) are dynamic and not pre-defined anywhere and user can enter them at random.

Is this possible? If yes, then how can I achieve it. (Possibly in nginx/apache.)

Answer (score 0):

From the nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html):

> A special wildcard name in the form `.example.org` can be used to match both the exact name `example.org` and the wildcard name `*.example.org`.

So you just need to use

```
server_name .example.com;
```

unstead of

```
server_name example.com;
```

Of course you'll need a wildcard DNS record for you domain for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I used vercel.com to get a quicker solution to my problem since they started supporting wildcard domains.

https://vercel.com/blog/wildcard-domains